# Oil pressure low on an 84 Ranger

Tags: engine, ford, oil, oil-change, ranger

I've recently changed the oil and filter on my 84 Ranger 2.8L V6. I used 10w-30 dino oil and filled it in range on the dip stick.

I noticed that after I changed the oil, the oil pressure gauge (on the dashboard) would be in the 'middle' portion. Several weeks later, and now the gauge is hovering over the 'low' portion. Checked the dipstick and it was still filled with oil.

What would be the causes of low oil pressure when the dipstick says there's enough oil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the oil filter. I've seen many times where the oil filter will cause a reduction in oil pressure and flow. Sometimes you just get a bad filter. Replace it with a quality filter. I'm talking a Motorcraft (since you have a Ford), Wix, ACDelco, STP, etc. There is one orange one in particular which I'd stay away from as they can cause more issues than they'll ever cure.

Comment: Is the oil pressure low only when the engine is fully warmed up, or is it also low when the engine's cold?

Comment: It's low both when it's cold and warmed up. I ordered a motorcraft filter on Amazon so now I'm just waiting for that to come in.